# Wix File Association - Misunderstanding

Tags: c#, wix, file-extension, file-association

I have an application and I want to use my own file extension that opens my application when double clicked.
I'm using Wix to build my installer and understand that I can make use of file association in my .wxs file. A snippet from the file currently looks like this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id ="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id ="RBUpdate.exe" Guid="*">
            <File Id="RBUpdate.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RBUpdate.TargetDir)RBUpdate.exe" />
            <ProgId Id ="MyProgID" Description="RBUpdate data files" Advertise="yes">
                <Extension Id ="rbu" ContentType="application/rbu">
                    <Verb Id ="open" Command="open" TargetFile="RBUpdate.exe" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;"/>
                </Extension>
            </ProgId>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id ="ProductFeature" Title="RBUpdateSetup" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id ="RBUpdate.exe"/>
    </Feature>
```

This builds fine but, if I'm honest, I'm new to this and not quite quite sure what it does.

How do I create an instance of my created file type? The files I'm creating are not going to be as a result of running the application and they will be manually made externally to the application, which it will then load. I simply want to be able to make an xml file, name it with the .rbu extension, and have it open with my application.

Comment: Have you tried creating an xml file, naming it with .rbu extension & then double clicking on it?

Comment: Wow it worked haha! There I was trying to create all sorts of .rbu files but didn't try renaming an xml file. I did state it was a misunderstanding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was very simply not renaming my xml files .rbu! This is a working example of how to use file association with wix anyway, to not completely waste time :L